# Dynamically create context menu on TouchDown Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a touch application in which I'm showing icons on the map. My requirement is like to show some options (like move, delete) on the icons touch. 
What is the best way to achieve this?

I'm very close to completing this application so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I'm very close to completing this" I've heard this before a few times. It usually means "I have almost got round to start thinking about it" :o) not wishing to judge

Comment: Is a context menu what you really need? Sounds like you just want things to appear when you touch something.  Need more information but really it sounds like this is not a question best suited for Stack Overflow because there's no technical hurdle, just an open ended architecture question.

Comment: @Erode That is the reason I put this question here in Stackoverflow. You guys can suggest me, instead of context menu what other ways I can have to show some options on icon's touch down event. Also In my question I've asked "what is the best way to achieve this".